# VB simple script error compiling loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a VERY simple script yet it is giving me an error while compiling it:

```
Sub Unit_Status()

    Dim temp, w, j
    On Error Resume Next

    For j=0 To 5
        temp = 0
        w = SmartTags("DB400")(j)

        If (w And &h10) Then 
            temp=4 '

        Else If (w And &h2) Then 
            temp=1 

        Else                
            temp=0 

        End If

        SmartTags("Unit_Status")(j)  =temp

    Next
End Sub
```

The SmartTags is a part of another piece of software. The error I am getting is an 'Unexpected Next'. Shouldn't  For close with Next?

Thank you - I am not familiar with VB just have to use it as a part of another software.

Comment: vb.net <> vbscript - please choose the language tag that actually applies to your question.

Comment: what about enabling the compile option `strict` in the vb.net project just to check syntax & datatypes? then revert these options back to the current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, you have 2 `If`s but 1 `End If`. So either close the second `If`

```
...
End If
End If
...
```

or change it to an `ElseIf`

```
ElseIf (w And &h2) Then 
temp=1
```